# laravel 5.2 config constant does not work on server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, config, constants

i seperate my strings and put them in Constant directory in textConstant.php file , in my localhost everythings are okey but when i uploads my code on my server the string fade out and nothing show in my screen ,

here is my constant file :

```
return [
        'title' => 'test',
         'book' => 'book_test',
       ];
```

and here is my code that use constant :

```
  <button>{{config('Constants.textConstant.book')}}</button>
```

please help me to solve my problem because my site cannot be usable, thanks alot :)

Comment: Can you check case sensitive of folders is it "Constants" or "constants"

Comment: replace `<button>{{config('Constants.textConstant.book')}}</button>` with `<button>{{config('constant.textConstant.book')}}</button>` as your directory name is `Constant` & you are using `Constants` as directory name in your code

Comment: is it working on your local machine??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run the following code over commandline if you have enabled the cache.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache.
```

Answer (score 0):

In CMD;
Write first

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Hope this will work.